# QListWidget send doubleClicked signal with no items

Tags: c++, qt, click, qt-creator, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget on a dialog that I want to do something (for example, open a QFileDialog window) when a user double-clicks on the QListWidget. Unfortunately, the `void doubleClicked (const QModelIndex & index)` only fires when there are items in the list.

Is it possible to get the widget to fire the signal whenever a double-click event is received, anywhere within the widget? Or is a different approach required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [install an event filter](http://web.mit.edu/qt-dynamic/www/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to the listwidget's viewport widget, something like this:

```
listWidget->viewport()->installEventFilter(this); // "this" could be your window object.
```

In the eventFilter method check for the `QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick` event:

```
bool YourWindowClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
         QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
         qDebug("Mouse double click %d %d", mouseEvent->x(), mouseEvent->y());
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd just like to add that since I had multiple QListWidgets to check, I also had to check obj. But since it is the QListWiget's viewport generating the event, you actually need to check obj->parent() against the your QListWidget to discover which was double-clicked on.